# Would you tell me how to equal the sentences, using BY THE TIME AND WHEN

Tags: past-tense, adverbs, past-perfect

By the time the first snowflake fell, Mario had made a warm fire and was enjoying the view.

When Mario  made a warm fire and was enjoying the view, the first snowflake fell.

Would you tell me if they are the same? if not, would you correct me till they become the same?

And, is there any specific rule to equal them?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think they're the same.

> By the time the first snowflake fell, Mario **had made** a warm fire and was enjoying the view.

explicitly indicates that the fire *had already been made* before he started to enjoy the view and at or before the time the first snowflake fell. The sequence is like this:

1. The fire was made.
2. Mario was enjoying the view.
3. The first snowflake fell.

(2 may take place at the same time as 3, but it is clear that 1 occurred and completed before.)

> When Mario **made a warm fire** and was enjoying the view, the first snowflake fell.

This one is a little unclear, I think. I'm not sure what it can mean. It might be better to rewrite it as either of these:

> When Mario **had made a warm fire** and was enjoying the view, the first snowflake fell.

to express the same thing as the first sentence above,

or

> When Mario **was making a warm fire and enjoying the view**, the first snowflake fell.

to make *making a warm fire* and *enjoying the view* the **ongoing** (happening) background of the event.

Answer (score 0):

They're basically the same.  The second sentence might make for more natural English if it were transformed like this:

> Mario made a warm fire and while (or as) he was enjoying the view, the first snowflake fell.

'When' tends to be more 'event-based':

> When John arrived on his bicycle, the first snowflake fell.

Comment: I am confusing with using BY THE TIME and WHEN, in such situations. When do they mean the same meaning?( BY THE TIME AND WHEN).